# Rewrite function to perform recursively (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, append

I need to change my current function empty_buckets(n) which creates a list (buckets) with 'n' amount of lists inside.

I have managed to get the function to decrease down to the base case but cannot get it to append a list on each recursion

Original Function

```
def empty_buckets(n)
    buckets = []
    for bucket in range(n):
        buckets.append([])
        print(buckets)
    return buckets
```

New Function

```
def empty_buckets(n):

    buckets = []
    if n == 0:
       return buckets
    else:
        return empty_buckets(n-1), buckets.append([])
```

The result should be a list of lists equal to the amount of n. I.e if n was 4 the result would be [[],[],[],[]]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a recursive problem, it seems to me you can just do `return [[] for _ in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just re-write your recursion like this -

```py
def empty_buckets(n, buckets):

    if n == 0:
       return buckets # base case - just return the buckets.
    else:
        buckets.append([]); # append a new empty list to the buckets
        return empty_buckets(n-1, buckets) # call recursion along with appended bucket list

print(empty_buckets(4, []))
```

**EDIT**
If you don't want to pass `buckets` to the method parameter, then you can do this -

```
def empty_buckets(n):
    if n == 0:
       return [];
    else:
        buckets = empty_buckets(n-1); # call the recursion
        buckets.append([]) # append an empty list
        return buckets
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with 'buckets' within the body of the function. Apologies, im fairly new to programming

Comment: @Mathias91 I have edited my answer with a different approach without passing `buckets` in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Each function has it's own copy of a variable(buckets in our case). So each time you call the method, it will re initialize buckets to an empty list and it will never get populated. So either you have to pass the list to the method as the parameter so that it will modify and give it to you or you must split this into two methods like this:

```
def g(buckets):
    buckets.append([])
    return buckets

def empty(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return g(empty(n - 1))
```